# is rails caching broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using active resource to send query to an external API.

To avoid abusing, results are cached one hour. Here is my code allowing me to cache my query :

```
    def find_with_read_through_cache(*arguments)
      logger.debug "----------------"
      logger.debug "arguments : #{arguments.join(' ')}"
      key = cache_key(arguments)
      logger.debug "key : #{key}"
      result = Rails.cache.read(key).try(:dup)
      logger.debug "result #{result}"
      logger.debug "#{key} #{result} #{self.cache_expires_in}"
      unless result
        result = find_without_read_through_cache(*arguments)
        logger.debug "write : #{Rails.cache.write(key, result, :expires_in => self.cache_expires_in)}"
      end
      result
    end
```

At the first query, everything is fine, i have a 200 request for each query i do and Rails.cache returns true :

```
----------------
arguments : players/ersykzer/
key : player/players/ersykzer/
result 
player/players/ersykzer/  3600
GET http://ws.maniaplanet.com:80/players/ersykzer/
--> 200 OK 109 (5376.3ms)
write : true
----------------
arguments : player/ersykzer/
key : canyonsolo/player/ersykzer/
result 
canyonsolo/player/ersykzer/  3600
GET http://ws.maniaplanet.com:80/canyon/rankings/solo/player/ersykzer/
--> 200 OK 115 (404.8ms)
write : true
----------------
arguments : player/ersykzer/
key : canyonmulti/player/ersykzer/
result 
canyonmulti/player/ersykzer/  3600
GET http://ws.maniaplanet.com:80/canyon/rankings/multiplayer/player/ersykzer/
--> 200 OK 169 (389.7ms)
write : true
----------------
arguments : zone/ {:params=>{:offset=>113, :length=>10}}
key : canyonsolo/zone//{:params=>{:offset=>113, :length=>10}}
result 
canyonsolo/zone//{:params=>{:offset=>113, :length=>10}}  3600
GET http://ws.maniaplanet.com:80/canyon/rankings/solo/zone/?length=10&offset=113
--> 200 OK 2012 (157.2ms)
write : true
----------------
arguments : zone/ {:params=>{:offset=>"2", :length=>10}}
key : canyonmulti/zone//{:params=>{:offset=>"2", :length=>10}}
result 
canyonmulti/zone//{:params=>{:offset=>"2", :length=>10}}  3600
GET http://ws.maniaplanet.com:80/canyon/rankings/multiplayer/zone/?length=10&offset=2
--> 200 OK 1849 (172.1ms)
write : true
```

However when the page is reloaded, two element seems to be unavailable in the cache :

```
----------------
arguments : players/ersykzer/
key : player/players/ersykzer/
result #<Player:0xaf25378>
player/players/ersykzer/ #<Player:0xaf25378> 3600
----------------
arguments : player/ersykzer/
key : canyonsolo/player/ersykzer/
result 
canyonsolo/player/ersykzer/  3600
GET http://ws.maniaplanet.com:80/canyon/rankings/solo/player/ersykzer/
--> 200 OK 115 (127.7ms)
write : true
----------------
arguments : player/ersykzer/
key : canyonmulti/player/ersykzer/
result 
canyonmulti/player/ersykzer/  3600
GET http://ws.maniaplanet.com:80/canyon/rankings/multiplayer/player/ersykzer/
--> 200 OK 169 (118.0ms)
write : true
----------------
arguments : zone/ {:params=>{:offset=>113, :length=>10}}
key : canyonsolo/zone//{:params=>{:offset=>113, :length=>10}}
result #<CanyonSolo:0xaee3180>
canyonsolo/zone//{:params=>{:offset=>113, :length=>10}} #<CanyonSolo:0xaee3180> 3600
----------------
arguments : zone/ {:params=>{:offset=>"2", :length=>10}}
key : canyonmulti/zone//{:params=>{:offset=>"2", :length=>10}}
result #<CanyonMulti:0xaeded10>
canyonmulti/zone//{:params=>{:offset=>"2", :length=>10}} #<CanyonMulti:0xaeded10> 3600
```

As you can see, the two element `canyonsolo/player/ersykzer/` and `canyonmulti/player/ersykzer/`, despite using the same key, are not returned by the cache.
Why is it not working? (rails 3.1)

Comment: Is the value you are trying to cache nil?

Comment: nope, on the contrary, it is a big XML

Comment: Is it > 1mb? What cache store are you using?

Comment: By the way it's the size of Marshal.dump(object_to_be_cached) that is relevant.

Comment: nope it is small, around 300 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from rails 3.1 to 3.2.0 it works. Nothing has changed in my code. It seems to be a rails bug.